# How to I rig two eyes?

Tags: materials, rigging

So I was making a Sonic model recently and this is the furthest I got, I began making the eyes (which are two spheres just split and duplicated)  and I was able to rig one side of them using the bones location and drivers to the material, but when I made a new rig for the other side, It worked, however it affected my first rig completely. The first rig was no longer moving the eye and every time I tried it, only one out of the two rigs would work. I saw an explanation to basically Constraint Location with the two rigs to a master rig, however I never managed to get it to work since it was too confusing to me. I'm really new to rigging the eyes so I never found any info on how to do it that went step by step. The picture below shows the rig and the materials I used for the eyes. The top bone is the main control for the eye so I can move it. The left one is for the pupils and the right is for the shine. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?
[image]
[image]